# Can't import using * with

Tags: python, import

I have the following code:

```
https://github.com/marcomusy/vedo/blob/master/examples/basic/colorlines.py

"""Color lines by a scalar"""
from vedo import *

pts1 = [(sin(x/8), cos(x/8), x/5) for x in range(25)]
l1 = Line(pts1).c('black')
l2 = l1.clone().rotateZ(180).shift(1,0,0)

dist = mag(l1.points()-l2.points())  # make up some scalar values

# The trick here is to think that the "body" of a line is a cell
# so we can color cells as we do for any other polygonal mesh:
lines = Lines(l1, l2).lw(4).cmap('Accent', dist, on='cells')

lines.addScalarBar(title='distance') # or e.g.:
# lines.addScalarBar3D(title='distance').scalarbar.rotateX(90).pos(1,1,2)

show(l1,l2, lines, __doc__, axes=1, bg2='lightblue', viewup='z')
```

However, this gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vedo.py", line 2, in <module>
    from vedo import *
  File "/Users/prikshetsharma/Documents/clotorch/src/clotorch/flight/vedo.py", line 4, in <module>
    pts1 = [(sin(x/8), cos(x/8), x/5) for x in range(25)]
  File "/Users/prikshetsharma/Documents/clotorch/src/clotorch/flight/vedo.py", line 4, in <listcomp>
    pts1 = [(sin(x/8), cos(x/8), x/5) for x in range(25)]
NameError: name 'sin' is not defined
```

However, sin is imported from numpy in the **init**.py file of vedo, so it should be defined in this file.

Comment: Your file is named `vedo.py`, it is trying to import itself, and that's what's causing the error.

Comment: You cannot just copy an arbitrary source file out of someone else's Github, name it whatever you like, and expect it to work. You need to install the whole package according to the instructions in the README.